# Is a modular approach always necessary when writing PHP class methods?

Tags: php, module

I currently have a class that performs all functionality in a single method `create()`.

```
// Approach 1
class My_Class {
    public function create() {
        // Lots of code.
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if I should break down my `create()` method into multiple smaller methods like so:

```
// Approach 2
class My_Class {
    public function create() {
        $this->assemble();
        $this->paint();
    }

    private function assemble() { // Code. }
    private function paint() { // Code. }
}
```

Methods `assemble()` and `paint()` are very specialised (they won't be reusable anywhere else in my project). This makes me wonder whether approach 2 is necessary in my case.

**My question:**

What is it about a method that indicates it should be broken down into smaller methods? I'm trying to understand when I should modularise and when I shouldn't.

Comment: It's purely opinion based and depends on so many parameters : purpose of the code ? re-usability of the code ? clarity of the code ? Just do as you want as long as you are not getting lost with your code, and not rewritting things again and again

Comment: In order to maintain a better overview I would create smaller methods

Comment: There are several good practices politics, but I like to be pragmatic because every project is different.

I mainly take in mind these two directives:

- If piece of code needs to be reusable : start new method or class to improve productivity
- If my current method has many lines of code and it's seems too complex: start new method to improve class organization and code legibility.

Comment: Main objective of OOP concept is re-usability, so for that we divide the too big code in to small function, but in your case it no need means, you follow the first approach.

Comment: Another example: If you break it down into two methods, you would be able in a child class to change the behaviour of `create()` by simply overwriting `paint()` and not the whole `create()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and guidance. I'm still in two minds whether to break my method down into smaller chunks. Reasons in favour seem to be better code clarity, reusability of the code, ability to override methods. Reasons against seem to be unnecessary effort (considering code reuse, and overriding won't happen in my case)

Answer (score 1):

The practical reason, or why it might be necessary if you want to keep your code DRY, that you would want to break out your one method into different methods would be if the actions performed by those methods currently or in the future might need to be called from different parts of the object or other objects (public).

Beyond the above case, it's then largely a matter of opinion, and I prefer to break things out into discreet methods to a reasonable certain degree to keep things tidy and so that there is some semantic story that you or another developer could read and understand. Instead of reading code code code, you read initialize(), assemble(), prime_surface(), paint(), theEnd(). The latter tells a better story.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official indication of when a method should be broken into piecies, I still (am forced to) work with code without objects so the code isn't segregated at all. What makes the difference is your personal use-cases for the class. If you choose to split up your main method, it's easier to document parts of the business logic rather than explain the whole class at once. Unit Testing is another component that could benefit, allowing to test the method seperately from others allows tests to rely less on the whole class.

Personally, I try to keep methods short and seperated as it more clear what the intents of your code are when you call a method `postForm($request, $dataMapper)` rather than block after block of code (and disecting those blocks of code to see where posting of the form starts, and where posting of the form ends). If you ever need to debug your code you might need to read every command in your method to find a bug. Seperated code might give you the advantage of knowing which piece of code is responsible for the bug, as you can give it a name that fits the context of the business logic.